# What does the typical electrical permit inspection look like for new branch circuits?

Tags: electrical

In general, is the inspector (USA- MD) only interested/allowed to inspect what the permit is for (new branch circuit, electric car charger)? Do they compare e.g the state of the electrical panel to "what's on file with the town"? If they see new-ish GFCI breakers are they going to investigate if the work was permitted?
Finally, is the explanation "it was done by the previous owner" sufficient?

Comment: do you realize that this is an international website?

Comment: This is going to vary dramatically by: jurisdiction (nation, state, county, city/town), by inspector, even by inspector's mood that day. I doubt that *generally* an inspector would compare to "what's on file", but if they see something *wrong* they can (I think) always call that out - e.g., if they are there for adding some circuits and see old circuits that were *never* legal - e.g., ground wire used as neutral, or wire that is not large enough for a circuit (14 AWG on 20A) they can write you up. In my area, my electrician said sometimes the inspectors (based on county rules) will check

Comment: for sufficient smoke detectors based on current rules (even though most things are "is it legal based on original installation date" but they didn't check that in my house. Really very much varies by jurisdiction.

Comment: rephrased the question and added details, thanks for the feedback

Comment: A new breaker (GFCI or otherwise) doesn't mean anything, because normally (I am sure there is an exception somewhere) a straight breaker replacement would not need a permit, and GFCI has been required for many circuits for a long time. Adding a *new* circuit is a different story, which you can't tell from the breaker but might (according to my electrician) be able to tell by looking at the cable or other components.

Comment: If something was done *correctly* by the previous owner, that is usually fine. If something was done *incorrectly* then the inspector can tell you to get it fixed - excuses don't matter.

Comment: It has been my experience that inspectors just spot check the work if it was permitted and done by a licensed electrician.  They look for gross things like cables being protected, maybe circuit breaker vs proper wire size.  Note that there may be multiple inspections involved, especially in the case of new construction.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the inspectors are there for what the permit has been pulled for but if they see something that isn't to code, they can investigate and possibly make you fix it if it could be a dangerous situation.  You're allowed to add GFCI breakers and outlets as replacements in most areas so that should be OK unless the GFCI breaker is for a spa or new garage that should have been permitted. "Done by previous owner" will not help you out of an unsafe, non permitted job that should have been. They can make you apply for a permit and fix the problem if it exists. This heavily depends on the local authorities.

Answer (score 2):

First, for an EV circuit, we tend to see first-timers go straight for a 50/60A circuit either because they think they have to, or a sense of "bigger is bettah".  It's not necessary for at-home charging (it's for travel), and can introduce new problems you were not expecting.  To start with, expect close scrutiny to the service's NEC 220.82 Load Calculation.

A 20A/240V circuit is 3 times better than level 1 charging, and will satisfy almost any need, especially in the dense east coast. (while urban driving is hard on gas car MPG, it's easy on EV range). EV climate control at low speeds is so efficient you can car camp on the road - just park and leave climate running and sleep. Tesla owners have done this and seen 7% drop in battery from running all night.

Generally inspectors are going to note imminent safety problems.  For instance if you have gaping holes in the panel due to removed twist-outs, or ungrounded circuits obviously run post-1965, missing grounding electrode, that kind of thing.  So don't present an obviously unfit panel, because that casts shade on the rest of the installation (and your qualifications) and invites further inspection. The panel should look competent. Do not snip all the wires short so they barely reach the breaker space they're on now. It does not help and is a bad idea generally.

If they're on a tear to check for particular public safety issues, like missing smoke detectors, GFCIs in bathrooms etc. they can make you install those even if the old work is technically grandfathered, because it's fairly trivial.

Since your other post seems to say installing a 15-20A circuit does not require a permit even, I don't imagine they will kick a fuss about GFCI retrofits.